# Parsing XML with Javascript (in Google Scripts)

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing, google-apps-script

I have temperature sensors streaming the temperature of three beehives, and would like to be able to parse the XML stream to provide the last value of the sensor.

I'd like to have:

- Sensor 1: 75 degrees (updated: 9:04 pm)
- Sensor 2: 75 degrees (updated: 9:04 pm)

etc.

I'm running following script in Google Scripts, but keep getting an error:

> Cannot find function getContentText in object <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Here is the simple script:

```js
function XMLing() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/79697.xml?key=[private key here]");

  var doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);
  var records = doc.getElements("current_value");
  var details = records[0].getText();

  return details;

}
```

Here is the XML:

```
<eeml xmlns="http://www.eeml.org/xsd/0.5.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="0.5.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eeml.org/xsd/0.5.1 http://www.eeml.org/xsd/0.5.1/0.5.1.xsd">
  <environment updated="2012-10-21T00:44:32.162393Z" created="2012-10-10T21:19:43.373591Z" id="79697" creator="https://cosm.com/users/greennomad">
    <private>false</private>
    <data id="sensor1tem">
      <current_value at="2012-10-21T00:44:32.019058Z">67.00</current_value>
      <max_value>618.0</max_value>
      <min_value>611.0</min_value>
    </data>
    <data id="sensor2tem">
      <current_value at="2012-10-21T00:44:32.019058Z">60.57</current_value>
      <max_value>61.5</max_value>
      <min_value>60.41</min_value>
    </data>
...
```

Comment: Perhaps, you're using an obsolete method of the API. I'd suggest checking the API documentation

Answer (score 1):

The error message is fairly obvious: your response object is actual text (the XML response) and not an object which has a getContentText() method. So this should work:

```
var doc = Xml.parse(response, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check which methods are available:

```js
if (!response.getContentText) {
    var props = [];
    for (var p in response) {
        props.push(p);
    }

    var name = typeof response;
    if (response.contructor) name = response.contructor.name;

    return name + " { " + props.join(", ") + " }";
}
```

My guess is that `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is either returning some error-code, or has a special response for XML-documents.

---

From the error-message, it would seem that `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is returning an XML-document directly. You might not need to call `Xml.parse()`:

```js
function XMLing() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.cosm.com/v2/feeds/79697.xml?key=[private key here]");

  var doc = null;
  if (response.getContentText) {
    doc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);
  }
  else if (response.getElements) {
    doc = response;
  }
  else {
    var name = typeof response;
    if (response.constructor) name = response.constructor.name;
    throw new Exception("Incompatible type: " + name);
  }

  var records = doc.getElements("current_value");
  var details = records[0].getText();

  return details;

}
```